# Laravel JSON response error handlining not working

Tags: laravel

I am trying to return an error response in app\Exceptions\Handler.php file.

```
public function render($request, Throwable $exception)
{
    if ($request->wantsJson() && $exception instanceof NotFoundHttpException) {
        return response()->json([
            'message' => 'Not found',
        ], 404);
    }

    return parent::render($request, $exception);
}
```

But it is returning this:

```
{
  "message": "",
  "exception": "Symfony\\Component\\HttpKernel\\Exception\\NotFoundHttpException",
  "file": "D:\\notes-api\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Routing\\AbstractRouteCollection.php",
  "line": 43
}
```

Don't really know why it is not working. Post of the posts and blogs suggest to update the handler.php file. Still can't fix this. Please help!

Comment: What Laravel version you're using?

Comment: I am using version 7.10.3

Comment: try `$request->expectsJson()` instead of `$request->wantsJson()` and see if it works.

Comment: Used `$request->expectsJson()`. Still does not work.